# No lee el for en el método agregar como es, creo que hay una posibilidad que no he definido y por eso me salta las otras :c

Tags: python, python-3.7

Error en el for del método agregar de la clase Gestor, creo que hay una condición que no he declarado, no se si es cuando la lista esta vacía... puesto que las demás están ya declaradas, el objetivo es que no se pueden repetir los nombres de usuario.

Es aquí lo que os digo, el programa esta preparado para:

1. si el usuario y contraseña de la lista es igual a el usuario y contraseña  del parámetro, el usuario ya existe.
2. si el usuario es igual a el usuario del parámetro, pero las contraseñas de ambos no, entonces se le pide al usuario que intente con otro nombre de usuario, porque ese ya esta en uso.
3. si el usuario del parametro, no esta en  la lista (self.usuario), entonces se puede registrar, porque no existe.(no importa si las contraseñas son iguales o diferentes a las de los usuarios que estan en la lista "self.usuarios".

   ```
   from io import open
   import pickle
   import time
   import os

   class Usuario:
       def __init__(self,usuario,contraseña):
           self.usuario = usuario
           self.contraseña = contraseña
       def __str__(self):
           return """\

   Usuario    Contraseña

   {}         {}""".format(self.usuario,self.contraseña)

   class Gestor():

       usuarios = []

       def __init__(self):
           self.load()

       def agregar(self,p):
           if len(p.usuario) == 0 and len(p.contraseña) == 0:
               print("\nError, debes llenar los campos.")
               time.sleep(3)
               os.system("cls")
               self.question()
           elif len(p.usuario) == 0 and len(p.contraseña) != 0:
               print("\nError, debes llenar los campos.")
               time.sleep(3)
               os.system("cls")
               self.question()
           elif len(p.usuario) != 0 and len(p.contraseña) == 0:
               print("\nError, debes llenar los campos.")
               time.sleep(3)
               os.system("cls")
               self.question()

           for u in self.usuarios:
               if u.usuario == p.usuario:
                   if u.contraseña == p.contraseña:
                       print("\nEl usuario ya está registrado.")
                       time.sleep(2)
                       os.system("cls")
                       print("""\

   ######################

   Bienvenido, {}.

   ######################""".format(p.usuario))
                       time.sleep(2)
                   else:
                       print("\nEste nombre de usuario ya esta en uso, por favor intenta con otro.")
                       time.sleep(2)
                       os.system("cls")
                       self.question()

               else:
                   self.usuarios.append(p)
                   self.guardar()
                   while True:
                       os.system("cls")
                       print("Registrando.")
                       time.sleep(1)
                       os.system("cls")
                       print("Registrando..")
                       time.sleep(1)
                       os.system("cls")
                       print("Registrando...")
                       time.sleep(1)
                       os.system("cls")
                       break
                   print("\nEl usuario ({}) ha sido registrado con exito.".format(p.usuario))
                   time.sleep(3)
                   os.system("cls")
                   print("""\

   ######################

   Bienvenido, {}.

   ######################""".format(p.usuario))
                   time.sleep(2)          

       def borrar(self,user):
           for u in self.usuarios:
               if u.usuario == user:
                   self.usuarios.remove(u)
                   self.guardar()
                   print("El usuario {} ha sido borrado.".format(user))
                   return
           print("El usuario {} no esta registrado.".format(user))
           pregunta2 = input("\n¿Deseas registrarlo?, [si-no]: ").lower()
           while True:
               if pregunta2 == "si":
                   self.question()
                   break
               elif pregunta2 == "no":
                   print("\nOk")
                   break
               elif pregunta2 != "si" or pregunta2 != "no":
                   print("Error, vuelve a intentarlo.")
                   self.previo()
                   break

       def guardar(self):
           fichero = open("database.pckl","wb")
           pickle.dump(self.usuarios,fichero)
           fichero.close()

       def load(self):
           fichero = open("database.pckl","ab+")
           fichero.seek(0)
           try:
               self.usuarios = pickle.load(fichero)
           except:
               pass
           finally:
               fichero.close()
               #print("Se han cargado {} usuarios".format(len(self.usuarios)))

       def mostrar(self):
           if len(self.usuarios) == 0:
               print("El fichero esta vacio.")
               return
           for u in self.usuarios:
               print(u)

       def question(self):
           g = Usuario(input("\nIntroduce un usuario: ").strip(),input("\nIntroduce una contraseña: ").strip())
           self.agregar(g)


       def question2(self):
           g = Usuario(input("\nIntroduce un usuario: ").strip(),input("\nIntroduce una contraseña: ").strip())
           self.verificar(g)


       def verificar(self,g):
           for u in self.usuarios:
               if u.usuario == g.usuario and u.contraseña == g.contraseña:
                   os.system("cls")
                   print("""\

   ######################

   Bienvenido, {}.

   ######################""".format(g.usuario))
                   time.sleep(2)
                   return

           os.system("cls")
           o = input("""\

   [V] PARA VOLVER A INTENTARLO

   [R] PARA REGISTRAR EL USUARIO


   El usuario no ha sido registrado, ¿que deseas hacer?: """).upper()

           while True:
               if o == "V":
                   os.system("cls")
                   self.previo()
                   break
               elif o == "R":
                   os.system("cls")
                   self.agregar(g)
                   break

               elif o != "V" or o != "R":
                   print("\nError, vuelve a intentarlo")
                   time.sleep(2)
                   os.system("cls")
                   self.otra()
                   break

       def previo(self):
           pregunta = input("\n¿Ya te registraste?, [si-no]: ").lower()
           while True:
               if pregunta == "no":
                   self.question()
                   break
               elif pregunta == "si":
                   self.question2()
                   break
               elif pregunta != "si" or pregunta != "no":
                   print("Error, vuelve a intentarlo.")
                   self.previo()
                   break
   #n = Gestor()
   #n.previo()
   #n.mostrar()
   #time.sleep(5)
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema no es que no tengas en cuenta alguna posibilidad, es cómo implementas el algoritmo de búsqueda. Tu código itera sobre `self.usuarios` y comprueba si el nombre del primer usuario en la lista coincide con el usuario a agregar, **si no coincide se pasa al `else` automáticamente (agregar usuario) sin tener en cuenta el resto de usuarios de `self.usuarios`**. De igual forma, si no existe ningún usuario registrado, no se entra en el `else` porque el `for` no llega a iterar siquiera, por lo que el usuario no se agrega.

Antes de agregar un usuario nuevo debes haber iterado **sobre todos** los usuarios registrados y comprobar que no existe. Realmente es muy simple de conseguir, solo tienes que mover el `else` final para que esté alineado con el `for`  y colocar un `break` que rompa el ciclo si el primer condicional es verdadero.

En la estructura `for-else` el código del `else` solo se ejecuta si el ciclo se topó con el final del iterable por si mismo, si en algún momento se rompió (aunque sea en el último item) no se entra en el mismo:

> ```
> >>> a = [1, 2]
> >>> for n in a:
>         if n == 2:
>             print("Encontrado")
>             break
>     else:
>         print("No encontrado")
>
> Encontrado
>
> >>> for n in a:
>         if n == 3:
>             print("Encontrado")
>             break
>     else:
>         print("No encontrado")
>
> No encontrado
> ```

Tu método `agregar` podría quedar algo así:

```
def agregar(self, p):
    if not p.usuario or not p.contraseña:
        print("\nError, debes llenar los campos.")
        time.sleep(3)
        os.system("cls")
        self.question()

    for u in self.usuarios:
        if u.usuario == p.usuario:
            if u.contraseña == p.contraseña:
                print("\nEl usuario ya está registrado.")
                time.sleep(2)
                os.system("cls")
                print("######################\n"
                      f"Bienvenido, {p.usuario}.\n"
                      "######################"
                      )
                time.sleep(2)

            else:
                print("\nEste nombre de usuario ya esta en uso, "
                      "por favor intenta con otro."
                       )
                time.sleep(2)
                os.system("cls")
                self.question()
            break # Rompemos el ciclo de búsqueda
    else:
        self.usuarios.append(p)
        self.guardar()
        for _ in range(3):
            os.system("cls")
            print("Registrando.")
            time.sleep(1)

        os.system("cls")
        print(f"\nEl usuario ({p.usuario}) ha sido registrado con éxito.")
        time.sleep(3)
        os.system("cls")
        print("######################\n"
              f"Bienvenido, {p.usuario}.\n"
              "######################"
              )
        time.sleep(2)
```

Observa que el `else` está al mismo nivel que el `for`, esto hace que solo se agregue el usuario si no se entró en el `if` (que contiene el `break`), por tanto solo se agrega el usuario si se ha recorrido `self.usuarios` al completo y no hay ningún usuario con ese nombre ya registrado.

Comment: muchas gracias a todos.